# How to sort comments by date/time posted in React (Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort the comments in my React (Firebase) App by date and time.

I have already tried orderByChild("date"), which did not work for my project.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const commentsRef = firebase.database().ref("Comments/News").orderByChild("date").limitToLast(5);
commentsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  let symptoms = snapshot.val();
  let newState = [];
  for (let item in symptoms) {
    newState.push({
      id: item,
      comment: symptoms[item].comment,
      date: symptoms[item].date
    });
  }
```

Here is my Firebase Database Setup:

[image: Firebase Setup]

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call `snapshot.val()` you lose all ordering information of the snapshot you call it on. This is because properties in a JSON object have no defined order.

So you need to loop over the matching nodes with the built-in `DataSnapshot.forEach()` function:

```
const commentsRef = firebase.database().ref("Comments/News").orderByChild("date").limitToLast(5);
commentsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
  let newState = [];
  snapshot.forEach(symptomSnapshot => {
    let symptom = symptomSnapshot.val();
    newState.push({
      id: symptomSnapshot.key,
      comment: symptom.comment,
      date: symptom.date
    });
  });
  // TODO: this is where you'll typically call setState(...)
});
```